# Won't break out of for loop

Tags: arduino-uno, pwm, piezo, buzzer

I'm new to Arduino and I'm trying to use PWM to generate a tone through a buzzer. I've created a `for` loop, however, the `for` loop doesn't seem to break when the variable `ms` is < 1000000.

```
int second = 1000000; //1 second in microseconds

void setup() {
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  //Play middle C for 1 second
  for(int ms=0; ms <= second; ms+=3830)
  {
    digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(1915);
    digitalWrite(3, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(1915);
    Serial.println(ms);
  }
  Serial.write("Finished C");
}
```

[image: Screenshot of serial monitor]

We can see on the serial output that the value of `ms` exceeds 1000000 but the `for` loop is still going. Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 4):

An `int` can't hold 1000000.  It is a *signed 16-bit variable*, which means it can only hold between -32768 and +32767.

To store larger numbers you need to use `long`, or `unsigned long` which are signed and unsigned *32-bit* variables.

Comment: Just one more question for my own understanding. Why on the serial output do values > 32767 display in the serial output?

Comment: `ms` may have been promoted to long since println expects long. However `second` will hold -31072. When you have the wrong variable type strange things can happen.

Comment: Ok thanks, at least I know now that it's important to think about what type a variable is.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Majenko's answer (an `int` on this platform can't hold a number greater than 32767) you have a second problem. You are evidently trying to make a middle C tone (261.6 Hz) by toggling a pin with a period of 1/261.6 seconds. However your Serial.println **takes time**. In particular at 9600 baud each byte you send will take 1/960 of a second (because there are 8 data bits, one start bit and one stop bit per byte), and assuming the number you are printing is roughly 4 digits, plus carriage return plus linefeed, you are sending 6 bytes for each time around the loop.

6 bytes of 1/960 (1042 µs) would be 6252 µs which completely dwarves your delays of 1915 µs.

Whenever you try to do things with timing loops you need to take account that **everything** in the loop takes time, not just your `delayMicroseconds` statements.